# What's the best way to make a catchy slogan?

Tags: technique, marketing, business-writing

I am trying to write a marketing slogan to draw people's interest.  Because it's a slogan I only have a few words to do this in.  How do I use just a few words to make the reader want to know more?  Should I focus on action verbs, use colorful adjectives, or what?

Currently my slogan is:

> Making deliveries more convenient.

This is true but does not feel exciting.  The idea is that we provide package pickup boxes in your neighborhood, where your mailbox is.

How do I make a slogan more clear and also "catchy"?

Comment: Requests to rephrase or critique text are off-topic here. Please see our site [tour] for more information about how to write a good, on-topic question for this site.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once; instead, you can edit your question using the "edit" link under the tags.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to make an edit to this question (to make it not a duplicate and more on-topic).  Please let me know if I've captured your intent.  That edit will put this into a review queue for reopening.